# Automatically verifying INSERTs when building a PHP(5.3.3) application

Tags: php, database, testing, mysql, test-automation

I am building a form in PHP. I would like to automatically verify that INSERT queries are successful, and populate data correctly, as opposed to running queries in Workbench or MySQL with every code change.

The only ways I can think of are to count the number of rows before and after, and see if they are equal, or write code to call posted data and compare it to the inserted data, query by query.

Is there some standardized way to go about this?

*A Note, I am stuck on PHP 5.3.3*

Comment: Are you using a testing framework?

Comment: @Snowman No I'm actually fairly new to automated testing as a process. All the code and DB testing tools I find seem to test code or the DB separately, or use a version of PHP above the one I'm on(5.3.3);

Comment: If the insert does not generate an error then you can assume it worked.  No need to get carried away with additional checks.

Comment: @Cerad It sounds horrible, but I can't control that error checking will be available in the development environment, and often `INSERTS` work, but that doesn't mean it is passing the correct data. I really do need to streamline/automate the manual testing I'm doing now.

Comment: Sorry but that makes no sense.  How would the data that you insert end up being different than what you inserted?  I am fairly certain that you are over thinking things.  But perhaps you could add a concrete real example to your question.

Comment: An Example: A User->Enters Data into Form->We Process/Sanitize/Validate->INSERT. If data breaks during validation or a name attribute has a typo after a change, data may come through as null during an insert, which doesn't always create an error, and goes on through.

Comment: The solution seems simple.  Don't insert data that does not pass validation.  If your validation is not picking up null values then adjust your validation.  Once again, consider updating your question with a real example of your concern.  It all seems to be quite vague.  You can of course retrieve the data after inserting but how would you know the data was correct after the insert but not know before the insert?

Comment: Every Query returns an array, you can compare your $_POST or $object->data to the data is query array. However, it is a bit much to do that myself, if someone has done it elsewhere. As for validation, it isn't just validation that has to be managed, processing and converting of data changes from what we receive to what we want.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you use a DML statement (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE), it always returns a integer number. Which can denote the number of rows updated while query execution, OR In case of insertion, it returns **ROW ID**(I am guessing you have a column named **id** with auto-increment, If yes this is the value created).